# Program for finding the nth term of arithmetic progression...how to solve this error?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

class Series {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int a, d, n;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter first term of A.P");
        a = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter difference");
        d = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the number of terms");
        n = sc.nextInt();
        Series s1 = new Series();
        s1.lastTerm();
    }

    public int lastTerm(int s) {
        int a, d, n;
        s = a + (n - 1) * d;
        return s;
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Series.java:15: error: method lastTerm in class Series cannot be applied to given types;
        s1.lastTerm();
          ^
  required: int
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code:

```
Series s1 = new Series();
s1.lastTerm();
```

You're calling the `lastTerm()` function. You declared your function to pass an `int` but in your `s1.lastTerm()` you're **not** passing any integer value to it. That's why the compiler is complaining.

This should be how you solve your problem:

```
public int lastTerm(int a, int d, int n)
{
    return a+(n-1)*d;
}
```

and call it as follows:

```
s1.lastTerm(a, d, n);
```

Comment: Glad to have helped. Please don't forget to accept the answer that helped by clicking on the tick mark underneath the score, on the left side of the appropriate answer section.

Comment: This is not good OOP-practice. `a` and `d` should be fields and initialised by the constructor, and `lastTerm` should be renamed to `getTerm`. While I appreciate you're just answering the question, OP clearly has very little programming knowledge, and so it would be wise to educate them in how things *should* be done, not just how they *can* be done.

Comment: I am assuming that the OP is getting tutored in class & that's. Part of an exercise. Until the OP learns OOP principles and practises, let's help solving current problems instead of further complicating his current understanding.

Comment: In that case why bother to create an instance of `Series`? It's completely pointless and the method can be static. Surely there's merit suggesting OP either go completely static or full OOP, not some ugly pointless hybrid?

Comment: That only the OP can answer, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

Pass all required parameters to the method

```
public int lastTerm(int firstTerm, int difference, int termCount) {
    return firstTerm + (termCount - 1) * difference;
}
```